# Create Template of Git Subtree Repository for simple reuse

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio, git, subtree

Recently i had extensive use of git subtree in a project.
Works all really fine. 
Now it turns out, that this project will be reused a lot of times, whenever i need this kind of project for a customer.
You can imagine something like a "framework".

So in Visual Studio I would create a "Solution Template" for simple reusing of the skeleton parts, to adapt only when needed.

But since this skeleton was built with a bunch of subtrees (each of them is a project for itself), i need a mechanism to recreate the git subtree references.
I don't want that every developer which uses the skeleton (via solution templates or cloning a repository) has to know about the references to recreate them.

So, is there a (best-practice?) way of accomplish this workflow?
Thanks in advance

Comment: Did you ever happen to find a solution to this?  Ours was sadly to keep the references in a text file in the top level project, which I've never been extremely satisfied with.

Comment: Unfortunately not. We tried to write powershell scripts to create all the references but it worked not as good as we intended. In the meanwhile we had all this subtrees thrown away and are working with nuget packages instead which will result in much more switching between different VS instances indeed, but its manageable though. So it has become needless for me. But if you ever come to a pretty solution please let me know and answer my question anyway :)

Comment: With "references to the subtrees" you mean the hashes that point to the tip of each of the subtrees in the repository?